# RuntimeError: Encountered unresolved custom op: FarthestPointSample

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, tensorflow-lite

**Provide the text output from tflite_convert**

I did try pointnet++  [https://github.com/charlesq34/pointnet2](https://stackoverflow.com) , and tried to inference with tf.lite or tflite-runtime, but both of them show the error message below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
predict = PointNetPredict('/kaggle/input/model-sign/model_sign.tflite')
File "/kaggle/working/pointnet3c1/models/pointnet_predict.py", line 27, in __init__
self.interpreter = self.init_model()
File "/kaggle/working/pointnet3c1/models/pointnet_predict.py", line 39, in init_model
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/interpreter.py", line 513, in allocate_tensors
return self._interpreter.AllocateTensors()
RuntimeError: Encountered unresolved custom op: FarthestPointSample.
See instructions: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_custom Node number 0 (FarthestPointSample) failed to prepare.Encountered unresolved custom op: FarthestPointSample.
See instructions: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_custom Node number 0 (FarthestPointSample) failed to prepare.
```

I noticed there were some custom ops(tf_ops) in project pointnet2, but how to convert these ops to tflite-runtime operators?